# (Very) High dimensional manifolds

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, soft-question, manifolds

Usually one regards manifolds up to dimension 4 as a part of *low dimensional topology*. There are plenty of various results which work only in low dimensional topology; especially in dimension 4. However still there are phenomena which occur only up from certain dimensions above 4: For example the famous result of Milnor, which states that each $PL$ manifold of dimension $n$ is in fact smooth provided that $n \leq 7$. My question is the following: Could you give an example of the (reasonable) theorem of the type "each manifold of dimension $n$ have some property $P$ provided that $n \leq K$ (and for $n>K$ there are  counterexamples)," where $K$ is some large number?

Comment: The Kervaire Invariant problem does not quite fit the parameters of the question, but I feel that it is worth mentioning as a near-example.

Answer (score 32):

The [smallest example](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306234.pdf) of a manifold that is homotopy equivalent to a topological group, but not rationally equivalent to a Lie group has dimension 1254.

Comment: +1. That's a very good example of a *large* K. Somehow I don't think the OP counts 6,7,8 as "large". I wouldn't either.

Comment: Actually it seems the authors only prove that their example has minimal rank, not minimal dimension. Still a very nice answer.

Comment: @DanPetersen -- indeed, they also mention a dimension-1250 example with rank 74.

Answer (score 18):

An important property of the cohomology of manifolds is the formality, which has been at the heart of a lot of work in rational homotopy theory. A simply connected topological space is said to be formal if its Sullivan minimal model is quasi-isomorphic (as an algebra) to its rational cohomology ring. Neisendorfer and Miller proved in their paper *Formal and coformal spaces* that every simply connected compact manifold of dimension lesser or equal to 6 is formal. There are counterexamples in dimension 7 and above, see for instance the papers *Examples of nonformal closed $(k −1)$-connected manifolds of dimensions $4k − 1$ and more* (Dranishnikov-Rudiyak) or *On nonformal simply connected manifolds* (Fernandez-Munoz) for instance.

Comment: As a  supplement: More general is every $(k-1)$-connected compact manifold of dimension $\leq (4k-1)$ formal for $k>1$. The result mentioned by Sinan Yalin follows for $k=2$. To get a counterexample in dimension 7, one can (as an alternative to the mentioned papers) realize (via Sullivan-Barge-Realization) the minimal Sullivan algebra $(\bigwedge<v,w,x,y,z>,d)$ where $deg(v)=deg(w)=2$, $deg(x)=deg(y)=deg(z)=3$ and $d(v)=d(w)=0$, $d(x)=v^2$, $d(y)=vw$, $deg(z)=w^2$ as a compact simply connected 7-manifold. This result will be  non-formal, since $<v,v,w>$ is a nontrivial Massey product.

Comment: Here is a way to obtain archipelago's example geometrically: Consider the map $S^2\times S^2 \to S^4$ that collapses the complement of a small disk to a point. Then pull back the Hopf fiber bundle $S^3\to S^7 \to S^4$ over this map, and obtain a fiber bundle $S^3 \to X \to S^2\times S^2$. The manifold $X$ is the simply connected non-formal 7-manifold whose minimal model is described in the above comment.

Answer (score 7):

> Theorem (Simons). Let $E\subset {\mathbb R}^n$ be of minimal perimeter. If $n\le7$, then $\partial E$ is a hyperplane.

If instead $n=2m\ge8$, then Simons provides the example of a minimal surface
$$x_1^2+\cdots+x_m^2=x_{m+1}^2+\cdots+x_{2m}^2$$
whose mean curvature vanishes identically. Bombieri, De Giorgi & Giusti proved that this cone is a minimal surface. This shows that the limit $n\le7$ in the Theorem is sharp.

Comment: You might want to mention that $E$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^n$ (presumably with smooth boundary), and also explain that "of minimal perimeter" refers to the fact that any local variation of $E$ that preserves the local volume of $E$ results in an increase of the perimeter (= area of $\partial E$). (Or should I only require the the first order variation of the perimeter be zero?)

Comment: @AndréHenriques Hey, I apologize for reacting to such an old comment - the thread popped up because of a new answer. In any case, what you wrote is incorrect. The set $E$ need not be open, it certainly wouldn't have a smooth boundary - note that the example given has a singular point at the origin -, and the definition of 'minimal perimeter' that you give is completely wrong. I'm sorry for phrasing this so bluntly, and I'm certainly not trying to be rude, but I wanted to be emphatic to prevent any misunderstanding from somebody else reading your comment.

Comment: @LeoMoos Thanks for pointing out my misunderstanding. Do you want to maybe elaborate on the correct meaning of 'minimal perimeter'?

Comment: @AndréHenriques Sure! Being of 'minimal perimeter', in other words being area-minimizing, means that $E$ has less area than any competitor $T \subset \mathbf{R}^n$ with the same boundary (meaning $T$ and $E$ lie in the same homology class), and which has $T \Delta E$ compact. It's not a local notion, and it has nothing to do with enclosed volume. What you describe sounds a bit more like locally isoperimetric surfaces. For example, spheres have this property, but they're obviously not minimal, let alone area-minimizing.

Answer (score 5):

It's not quite as large as 1254, but there is a conjecture about the Yamabe problem which holds small dimensions but fails once the dimension is 25 or more.

When $(M^n, g)$ is a smooth compact Riemannian manifold of dimension
$n \geq 3$ without boundary, the Yamabe Problem consists of finding
a metric $\widetilde{g}$ which has constant scalar curvature and is conformal to g (i.e., satisfies $\widetilde{g} = u^{4/(n-2)} g$ for some smooth function $u$). The Compactness Conjecture stated that the set of solutions to this problem are compact in the $C^2$ topology unless $(M, g)$ is conformally equivalent to the round sphere. In 2008-09, there were a series of papers on this topic where it was shown that conjecture holds for $n \leq 24$ [1], but fails for all dimensions 25 and higher [2,3].

[1] *Khuri, M. A.; Marques, F. C.; Schoen, R. M.*, [**A compactness theorem for the Yamabe problem**](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1228400630), J. Differ. Geom. 81, No. 1, 143-196 (2009). [ZBL1162.53029](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1162.53029).

[2] *Brendle, Simon*, [**Blow-up phenomena for the Yamabe equation**](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3840), J. Am. Math. Soc. 21, No. 4, 951-979 (2008). [ZBL1206.53041](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1206.53041).

[3] *Brendle, Simon; Marques, Fernando C.*, [**Blow-up phenomena for the Yamabe equation. II**](https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.3841), J. Differ. Geom. 81, No. 2, 225-250 (2009). [ZBL1166.53025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1166.53025).[3]

Comment: Is there any conceptual explanation for 'why' things change at dimension 25? It seems a bit mysterious - I skimmed the last paper by Brendle and Marques, and they just mention that it ties in with the eigenvalues of some bilinear form becoming negative.

Comment: @LeoMoos The paper to read is the first one, which introduces the bilinear form and reduces the proof to showing that it is positive definite. However, I don’t have a good conceptual explanation for why things change once you get to 25.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your comment! (It all seems a bit mysterious, but then again I really know very little about the Yamabe problem.)